# What the difference List list = new ArrayList() and List list = new LinkedList()

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

I got a question in my mind that:
What the difference 
1) List list = new ArrayList()
2) List list = new LinkedList() ?
No matter I initialize list in the both way above, still it can only use method in List, but not either ArrayList or LinkedList, isn't it?

I read from a website (http://www.corejavaguru.com/blog/java/new-arraylist), stated that it is known as "programming to an interface", which easy for a developer to change from ArrayList to LinkedList or vice versa in future. But no way for me to use method of ArrayList/LinkedList if I initialized in the way shown above, even it is flexible to change the way of initialize. I believe there is a reason. Hope to find answer for it.

Comment: The rough difference is you should use `ArrayList`, you should not use `LinkedList`. I did the latter once in my 20 years as a Java programmer, and in retrospect I regretted.

Comment: @OleV.V. Why one should not use LinkedList?

Comment: I think the question is worded confusingly, but I believe that the OP is asking about the reasons for declaring the variable type as `List` rather than declaring the variable type as the actual concrete implementation class, either `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. So I don't feel that this duplicates the linked question.

Comment: agree with @Bobulous. The title is misleading.

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov You can if you like, but why should you? In the 9 out of 10 cases where performance doesn’t matter, you can toss a coin. When it does matter, prefer `ArrayList`. I have never seen a case where `LinkedList` performed better, neither time-wise nor space-wise. Not even when insertions and deletions in the middle were sometimes done.

Comment: I read from website, initialize List list = new ArrayList() is better than ArrayList list = new ArrayList(), because of the flexibility (developer might want to change from ArrayList to LinkedList). But I wonder what the purpose to have the flexibility to change from ArrayList to LinkedList. Because with the initialize List list = new ArrayList() or List list = new LinkedList(), still we only can invoke method from List interface class. So to post at here to find the answer from professional around =)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you created a variable named `list` with the type of [List (Interface)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) as a pointer.

In the 1st case:
    List list = new ArrayList()
You initiated the `list` variable with class [ArryaList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which is an implementation of the [List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), in short:

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface

In the 2nd case:
    List list = new LinkedList()
You initiated the `list` variable with class [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), which is an implementation of the [List interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), in short:

> Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces

In conclusion, in both cases you'll get a list which you can use according to the list interface definition. The main differences are:

1. implementation it varies in terms of performance and memory usage
2. each implementation might contain additional functionality when used
   in the specific implementation context